# Why keys are absent in map

Tags: dictionary, go

I created a map:

```
l := make(map[*A]string)
```

where A is:

```
type A struct{}
```

Then added key-values into it:

```
a1 := &A{}
a2 := &A{}
a3 := &A{}

l[a1] = "a1"
l[a2] = "a2"
l[a3] = "a3"
```

I expected to see all values ("a1", "a2", "a3") while doing `range`

```
for k, v := range l{
    fmt.Println(k, v)
}
```

But I see only the last one.

Why that happens?
https://play.golang.org/p/GSdUWzExxLK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your struct has no fields, Go optimizes away all pointers to it to the same address, so you're using the same key every time. Give the struct a field (even if you never put a value in it) and you'll get your expected behavior.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/n-WUZ9wqpGJ

You can read more about empty structs (including this pointer behavior) [on Dave Cheney's blog](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct).

It's mentioned only briefly in the spec, under [Sizes and Alignments](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Size_and_alignment_guarantees), and is in fact the very last sentence in the spec:

> A struct or array type has size zero if it contains no fields (or elements, respectively) that have a size greater than zero. Two distinct zero-size variables may have the same address in memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `A` is an empty structure. As it cannot change go always assigns it the same memory address. If you add a field to `A` it will start working:

```
type A struct{a string}

func main() {
    a1 := A{}
    a2 := A{}

    l := make(map[*A]string)
    l[&a1] = "a1"
    l[&a2] = "a2"

    for i, v := range l{
        i := i
        fmt.Println(&i, v)
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
0x40e138 a1
0x40e150 a2
```

https://play.golang.org/p/hYzU73kbVPV

Dave Cheney goes into more depth here:

https://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct